# How to web scrape JSON file with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, json

I'm trying to gather data from a JSON file: https://www.g2a.com/marketplace/product/auctions/?id=780532

However, whenever I try and get data I run into errors stating I don't have permission to access this webpage yet it works fine within my browser.

Scraping data using request and cheerio libaries.

```
const request = require('request-promise'); // name of the libary
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const URL = "https://www.g2a.com/marketplace/product/auctions/?id=780532";


(async()=>{

    const response = await request({
        uri: URL,
        headers:{
            'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise'
        }
    });

    let $ = cheerio.load(response);

   // let title = $('div[class="title_wrapper"] > h1').text(); // This div is hidden under many others but because the name is unique it finds it. H1 is underneath the div and just contains text
    //let rating = $('span[itemprop="ratingValue"]').text(); // Same as above

    let price = $('span[itemprop="value"]').text(); 

    console.log(price);
})()
```

Outputting some values from the JSON.

Comment: Do you have to log in to see things in your browser?

Comment: Its got nothing to do with your code, postman also gets that response. Not sure how its done, but the requests are blocked from non browsers. They probably require you to authenticate for api access.

Comment: @zero298 I don't, no. It's just a link.

Answer (score 0):

This server is requiring you to send a few extra request headers:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

This is likely a way to keep the responses to browsers-only.  Just add those to your request headers, and you'll be good to go.

I figured this out by using [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to monitor a successful request from the browser, then used its HTTP request composer panel to whittle down just the request headers that were required.

Do consider contacting this host to get permission for whatever data you're accessing, and whatever you're doing with it.  Report this bug to them, maybe they'll give you a proper API key.

Answer (score 0):

The real issue lies in the access method of the website.
It does not work with nodejs server is because of the security implementations in the server of the site that you are trying to access. Getting yourself authorized is one of the best ways to not to get error.
 
The work around I came up with is:

```
const morgan = require('morgan');
const express = require('express');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const app = express();
app.use(morgan('combined'));
app.listen(8080, () => {
console.log('hosted on 8080');
});
let html;
(async () => {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false
});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://www.g2a.com/marketplace/product/auctions/?id=780532', {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle0'
});
await page.screenshot({
    path: 'example.png'
});
html = await page.content();
await browser.close();
console.log(html);
})();
```

> **Note: You can now do whatever and however you wanna do with "html" variable.**
>   
> You can choose to remove:
>   `await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});` because all it does is saves a screenshot.

If you need a light weight tool then you have a option to use ***puppeteer-core***, but that would require a local installation of chrome.

I personally prefer Puppeteer. There are other substitutes for puppeteer.